# Use FileReader Class to read file from location Java

Tags: java, filereader

I'm using the FileReader class to try and access a .txt file in the same directory. The only way I've made it work is by using the directory path starting from Users.

Worth noting - I'm using intellij community edition on Mac

code

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("/Users/tuckerbeauchamp/Desktop/Java-Class/Famous Scientist/src/com/names.txt"));
```

error I get when using just "names.txt"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: names.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.FamousCS.main(FamousCS.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

[image: Files]

Comment: The same directory as what? The source code, the root of a part of the class path, one of the class files themselves, or where you're running the code from?

Comment: if you are using ide, the current working directory will be where you have placed your source files. Keep names.txt in the exact location as your source file and you dont need full path

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama Your current working directory will be where your code is executing, not where your source files are

Comment: I have everything in the com folder but if I use just "names.txt" I get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the text file in the same directory as your source file(s), the text file will be available in the class path when you run the program. So you can access the file using the Class loader:

```
InputStream stream = FamousCS.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/names.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same directory as the class, simply putting

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("names.txt"));
```

will also work. No need to load files through class loaders and all.

Also in similar situations, also use ***File.getAbsolutePath()*** to check where exactly the file is being looked upon..